# Is there a cloud product out there to handle authentication and authorization, password resets etc for websites?

Tags: web-apps

I am going to be making several websites for a clients.

I look for components that I can use to cut down on the development time
and deliver higher quality.  As part of that  I am looking for a preferably 
language agnostic cloud service that can handle at a high level:

- Authentication,
- Authorization and
- Accounting

Google, Facebook, Persona can handle Identity (Authentication), but not the rest.

Basically an API conceptually something like this:

- SomeService.LogIn()
- SomeService.LogOut()
- SomeService.Lock()
- SomeService.Cancel()
- SomeService.HasPermission()
- SomeService.GivePermission()
- SomeService.RevokePermission()
- SomeService.IsMemberOf()
- SomeService.AddAsMembmerOf()
- SomeService.RemoveAsMemberOf()

The service would also handle the storing of user accounts, handle password,
password resets, securing the login process.

In addition to having a cloud based API that I use inside my website 
for AAA.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: Does it really have to be a cloud service? That sounds more like something I'd want as a library — externalizing authentication is one thing, but I wouldn't want to externalize my user database.

Comment: I would want it as a service, so I can externalize this part of the websites.

Comment: It sounds like you need [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) in combination with software to manage accounting. I would consider keeping authentication separate than accounting as it will aid security (authentication is then kept within its own self contained, external service).

Answer (score 3):

I agree that OAuth 2.0 is a good choice for Authentication and Authorization. If the different clients need a different access to your API, then you can use scopes in OAuth 2.0 specification. 
You can take a look at http://apifest.com - ApiFest is an open-source Java project you can check on github. It contains an OAuth 2.0 implementation(ApiFest OAuth 2.0 Server) and API management server - ApiFest Mapping Server.
Good luck!